# Are 'coreservicesd' & 'syslogd' disguises for keylogger apps?

Tags: malware

this [article](https://macmyths.com/how-to-know-if-my-mac-has-keylogger/) says so, they may be shilling for osx uninstaller app thoughh

> Look for ‘coreservicesd’ to find Aobo
>   Check for ‘Elite Keylogger’ when searching Elite Keylogger. However, the version I installed was free and it did not hide, so I don’t know how the process name will change for someone who buys a product.
>   And finally, ‘Refog’ appears as ‘syslogd’

Answer (score 3):

## Check Code Signatures

If you suspect a process on your Mac is disguising itself as part of macOS, check the process's digital code signature. You can do this with the `codesign` binary:

```
/usr/bin/codesign -d -vvvv /System/Library/CoreServices/coreservicesd
```

If there is no signature, it is not from Apple.

If the `Authority` fields do not list `Apple Root CA`, then it is not signed by Apple or one of their partners.

Comment: It's likely (if SIP is on) that malware passing itself off as coreserviced would not be at that location. All you're doing there is checking that Apple's own file has the correct codesign, which it will.

Comment: Yes, I am showing the command run on the real `coreservicesd` binary. If the questioner wants to check any other binary – which they suspect – the command needs altering.

Answer (score 1):

Both coreservices and syslogd are legitimate programs included in the standard installation of macOS. Thus seeing those in the process list is not in itself an indication of keyloggers.

However, it is possible that a keylogger could be camouflaging itself by using a well-known process name. You would need to identify the keylogger by something other than the process name though.